# How to solve the error : cannot convert from int to float& at line 4

Tags: c++

```
inline float& Matrix::operator()(const int ax, const int ay) const {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (ax >= ivWidth || ay >= ivHeight || ax < 0 || ay < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Exception EMatrixRangeOverflow: x = " << ax << ", y = " << ay << std::endl;
        return 0; // line 4: here the problem!
    }
#endif
    return ivData[ivWidth * ay + ax];
}
```

The error is on line 4 : `return 0`.

Comment: Could you provide a more... *formatted* question?

Comment: You should always provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear how to resolve the error because it is not clear what the code is intended to do.

Comment: You should throw an exception instead of returning a value

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> inline float& Matrix::operator()(const int ax, const int ay) const {
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>         return 0; // line 4: here the problem!
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Your problem can be reduced to:

```
float& f()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Or even further to:

```
int main()
{
    float& f = 0;
}
```

And indeed, this does not make sense at all. You are trying to create a non-const reference to an integer literal. How could this possibly work? **It's as if you wanted the power to modify the meaning of the value zero *itself*.** C++ does not allow that. Zero means zero and will do so forever.

A `float&` must always refer to an actual modifiable `float` object (or to a modifiable `float`-compatible object). Therefore, there are no special values or error return codes suitable for a function returning a `float&`.

So much for the theory. Now, what to do about it?

1. It looks very wrong to return a `float&` in a `const` member function. You almost certainly want to return a `float`.
2. In order to report an error, throw an exception or use `assert`.

Throwing an exception:

```
inline float Matrix::operator()(const int ax, const int ay) const {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (ax >= ivWidth || ay >= ivHeight || ax < 0 || ay < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception EMatrixRangeOverflow: x = " + std::to_string(ax) + ", y = " + std::to_string(ay));
    }
#endif
    return ivData[ivWidth * ay + ax];
}
```

Asserting:

```
inline float Matrix::operator()(const int ax, const int ay) const {
    assert(!(ax >= ivWidth || ay >= ivHeight || ax < 0 || ay < 0));
    return ivData[ivWidth * ay + ax];
}
```

Note how you don't actually need a `_DEBUG` macro. There is the standard `NDEBUG` to control the behaviour of `assert`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the problem `inline float&` in `&` this mean you must return an object (`float`) or member or `variable` (what else)...

I don't know what you try to do for `&` but you can fix it to add `member in class` or `general variable` like

```
float ZERO = 0;
inline float& Matrix::operator()(const int ax, const int ay) const {
#ifdef _DEBUG    
    if (ax >= ivWidth || ay >= ivHeight || ax < 0 || ay < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Exception EMatrixRangeOverflow: x = " << ax << ", y = " << ay << std::endl;
        return ZERO; // here the fix
    }
#endif
    return ivData[ivWidth * ay + ax];
}
```

By reference (`&`) must pointer to `variable` or `object`, in your case is `variable of float`

Comment: This means a client can change the value of `ZERO` and set it to 1, 47 or 10000.